# Windows Forms control wrapping in WPF doesn't work properly

Tags: wpf, winforms, data-binding, datepicker

I need to wrap the Windows Forms `DateTimePicker` to use it in my WPF 3.5 application. I've made a control out of it:

```
<UserControl><WindowsFormsHost>
<wf:DateTimePicker x:Name="picker" ValueChanged="DateTimePicker_ValueChanged"/>
</WindowsFormsHost></UserControl>
```

and here is the backing code:

```
    bool suppressUpdates;

    public DatePicker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void DateTimePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!suppressUpdates)
            SetValue(SelectedDateProperty, picker.Value);
    }

    public DateTime SelectedDate
    {
        get {return (DateTime)GetValue(SelectedDateProperty); }
        set
        {
            suppressUpdates = true;
            picker.Value = value;
            SetValue(SelectedDateProperty, value);
            suppressUpdates = false;
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDateProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedDate", typeof(DateTime),
   typeof(DatePicker), new UIPropertyMetadata(DateTime.Now));
```

Then I use it at a WPF window:

```
<mui:DatePicker Width="300" SelectedDate="{Binding
Path=TheDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

It is bound to `INotifyPropertyChanged`-enabled viewmodel. All other controls bind to it just fine but my DateTimePicker doesn't get the date value specified in the viewmodel. However, it propagates its value changes back to it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it was simple.

```
    private void DateTimePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetValue(SelectedDateProperty, picker.Value);
    }

    public DateTime SelectedDate
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(SelectedDateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedDateProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedDate", typeof(DateTime), typeof(DatePicker), new UIPropertyMetadata(DateTime.Now, textChangedCallback));

    private static void textChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DatePicker input = (DatePicker)d;
        input.picker.Value = (DateTime)e.NewValue;
    }
```